Remote Desktop closing session when I block the computer
I have a MacBook Pro and I use the Microsoft Remote Desktop app to connect to some servers running Windows Server 2019.
Every time I leave my desk, I lock the computer.
But when I return and unlock it, the RemoteDesktop session reconnects, but all programs I was using inside the session are closed, just as if I had logged out of the RDP session.
I don't care if the session closes, but I don't want all programs closing in the process.
This happens with only one particular Windows Server 2019 connection.

It's likely the server is configured to log off users after x amount of idle time or after losing connection. You'll have to contact the server admin and ask if they are willing to change it to keep your user logged on after disconnect.

Your RDP client might also have an option to keep the session alive. For a Windows client the answer is here, but I don't know which client you're using on the Mac.
